# when I check one item show in toast but I want that when I check multiple item it's shows it's name in toast

Tags: android, android-listview

when I check one item show in toast but I want that when I check multiple item it's shows it's name in toast.

```
String[] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Resources r = getResources();
        items = r.getStringArray(R.array.items);

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                items);

        setListAdapter(aa);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), items[position].toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWXbY.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
// make temporary array to store your List view value   
 private ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList();

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

            tempArray.add(items[position].toString());
            String allItems = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.size(); i++) {
                allItems = allItems + "\n" + items[position].toString();
            }
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ""+allItems, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```